# What is the SOQL to get all Public Calendars, in a Salesforce instance?

Tags: calendar, salesforce, soql

Does anyone know how to perform a query to get all public calendars?  You can see the list by going to Setup ... Customize ... Activities .. Public Calendars and Resources

What are these calendar objects?

My goal is to find a way to show these calendars in a VisualForce page to make it easier for users to find them.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a .getSobjectType() on the ID it comes up as a calendar object. When you try and query that object it says it's not available. It looks like the custom setting is the only route for now.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, Salesforce hasn't directly exposed the Public Calendar object for customers to query directly.

Public Calendars seem to fall into the 023 namespace, which is a standard object, but I can't find any object in the Schema that have that namespace, which leads me to believe that SFDC has hidden them from us.

Comment: Thanks. I came to this same conclusion but we can hope there is a workaround out there!   In the meantime, I'll be creating a Custom Setting object to store the calendar Ids.  This is just a pain to manage!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the list in Visualforce, you could use a workaround using the PageReference GetContent() method on the Calendar page and then fetch the details from the html.

Note that this won't work in APEX triggers..

```
Public Class CalendarResource{
    public Id crId {get;set;}
    public String label {get;set;}
    public String type {get;set;}
}

Pagereference r = new PageReference('/_ui/common/data/LookupResultsFrame?lkfm=swt&lknm=cal&lktp=023&cltp=resource&lksrch=#');
String html = r.getContent().toString();
List<CalendarResource> cals = new List<CalendarResource>();

Matcher m = Pattern.compile('lookupPick\\(\'swt\',\'cal_lkid\',\'cal\',\'\',\'(.*?)\',\'(.*?)\',\'\',\'\'\\)">(.*?)</a></TH><td class=" dataCell  ">(.*?)<\\/td><\\/tr>').matcher(html);

//While there are labels
while (m.find()) {
    //system.debug(m.group(3));
    //system.debug(m.group(4));

    CalendarResource cr = new CalendarResource();
    cr.crId = m.group(1);
    cr.label = m.group(2);
    cr.type = m.group(4);
    cals.add(cr);
}
for(CalendarResource cr : cals){
    system.debug(cr.crId+'__'+cr.label+'___'+cr.type);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the current API version by: "SELECT Id,Name FROM Calendar where Type='Resource'